# PostgreSQL - using an aggregation result and a specific row in the same request

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My problem is a bit hard to explain, so here's an example of what I'd like to do:

```sql
SELECT AVG(num) - num, date
FROM my_tbl
```

What I'm doing here is accessing both a result of aggregation (`AVG(num)`) and a specific row (`num`) at the same time.

This example doesn't work, here's one that does the same thing and works:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT AVG(num) FROM my_tbl) - num
FROM my_tbl
```

My problem with that second request is that `my_table` is queried 2 times, as if it was 2 different tables

So my question is: is it possible to make 2 different types of selection, and query the table only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
SELECT AVG(num) OVER () - num, date
FROM my_tbl;
```

Whether this reads the table once or twice is up to the optimizer.  I'm not sure this will be any faster than your version.  But it is a more concise way to write the query.